# VirtualBox Linux Guest Mac Host runs really slow

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, performance

I have performance issues in VirtualBox, the quest operating system runs really slow and laggy.

The configuration:

- Host: MBP 2019, 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, 16 GB RAM, MacOS Sonoma 14.2
- Guest: Kali Linux, up-to-date, XFCE
- VirtualBox:  7.0, Base memory: 8192 MB, 8 CPUs, Video memory: 128
  MB, VMSVGA, Enabled 3D Acceleration. Guest addition is installed.

I tried different graphics controllers and also to turn on and off the 3D Acceleration. I tried different views: scaled mode, just scaling it down etc.

None of these seem to work. I also don't find good Google hits.

Comment: We need more detail on the Mac, because 8CPUs & 8GB assigned to the VM sounds a little over-generous, swamping the Mac itself, but tbh, VB is just slow compared to Parallels or Fusion.

Comment: I added the info to the question.

Comment: OK, with an 8-core HT CPU, you're OK to set 8 cores in the VM [assuming the VM can use them effectively]. 8 out of 16GB total RAM might be just a little over, I'd drop that back to 6. The rest will just be VB being slow, I'd have thought. I presume you're running the VM from the Mac's internal SSD, or something similarly fast?

Comment: I am posting from a Kali machine here.  I use well under 1/2 my host memory for my Kali machine. I use only 2 cores for CPU.  The VM works well. Try assigning less host resources to the VM.  I also use VMware instead of VBOX.

Comment: I tried with the suggested settings, but it is still slow. Especially when I start Firefox. But the slowing down is random. I have a feeling that is due to the high resolution that caused by the Guest Addition resizing, even though I switched to a fixed size. (I have this issue with other Linuxes too, but just after installing Guest Additions, but that I need in this case.)

The difference is that I'm using VBox. I would like a free solution, VMware seems to not have a free plan.

Comment: VMware does offer a free [personal use license](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal). You can have VirtualBox and Fusion Player installed at the same time. Also, kali has [pre-built virtual machines](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines) which may perform better.

Comment: Also, did you install the VirtualBox Extension Pack? This is not the same thing as Guest Additions.

Comment: Yeah, the Extension Pack is installed. I tried VMWare and that is the solution. Works very well! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David mentioned in the comments, I switched to a free VMWare instance that doing the job very well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **booting with mitigations off**? I seem to remember that VirtualBox did not handle well the Intel CPU vulnerability mitigation management (which, on a personal system, shouldn't be an issue).

They did get to fix that, but maybe on MacOS it still doesn't work as it should.

In the kernel parameters at boot,

```
mitigations=off
```

See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554908/disable-spectre-and-meltdown-mitigations).